# Applications of Pluripotential Theory in real world

Tags: book-recommendation, applications, several-complex-variables, online-resources, potential-theory

I am reading for a math PhD with research in Pluripotential Theory (a subfield in Several Complex Variables). I particularly do study and develop theory related to extremal functions associated with a convex body. My work is extremely abstract where I see no relation to the real world stuff. I once talked with my advisor and asked if there are any direct or indirect real world applications. He did not specifically give me a clear answer. Instead he talked about generally that there are applications of complex analysis in physics, engineering, etc. So, I am still curious to know if there are any applications and why researchers spend time on discovering many complicated theories. Is there anyone who is able to provide me possible real world applications of my work? If you could at least give me links to resources (such as books, papers, articles) that talk about these stuff explicitly, I would highly appreciate it!

Comment: Hi, actually you can look at quantum mechanics and especially quantum computers when potentiental sink form is a part of calculation. It may be an engineering application.